# C#-Framework for extending Resource-File-Usage

Tags: c#, .net, localization

In .NET we've got Resource files which are great for allowing providing translations across applications.

I'm currently building a MVC Application and using different resx-files per view, like AccountRes.fr-FR.resx, AccountRes.en-US.resx & AccountRes.resx for the AccountView, and just the same for the other views.

I want to integrate a mechanism, that works like the following:

1. Use string/value of the resx-file
2. If there's none available, use string/value from a database.

Which C#-framework allows integration of this logic with just a bit of implementation overhead?